# "Invalid OAuth access token" on Marketing API in Python

Tags: python, oauth, access-token, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to access Facebook Marketing Api in Python, but I encounter some issues with the access token.
I run the following code:

```
def get_app_access_token(app_id, app_secret):
     args = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': app_id,
        'client_secret': app_secret}

     f = urllib2.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" +
                          urllib.urlencode(args))

     resp = json.loads(f.read())
     ### resp gives me {"access_token":"xxxxxx|yyyyyy", "token_type":"bearer"} 
     ### so I extract yyyyyy as my access_token
     result = resp["access_token"].split('|')[1]

access_token = get_app_access_token(APP_ID, SECRET_KEY)
api = FacebookAdsApi.init(APP_ID, SECRET_KEY, access_token)
account = AdAccount(AD_ACCOUNT)
adsets = account.get_ad_sets(fields=[AdSet.Field.name])
```

And I get the error "Invalid OAuth access token" on the last line.

Do you know what I did wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think changing `result` from `result = resp["access_token"].split('|')[1]` to `result = resp["access_token"]`

The Python API can use the format of `"xxxxxx|yyyyyy"` if you are feeding it to `FacebookAdsApi` however unless everything is setup properly on the Facebook developer settings for the tokens you get, I am not sure You can get proper access.

Using above I can get to the ad account okay. However my permissions for client tokens didn't allow for access to campaigns and I was using a depreciated API.